# Android 5.0: Programmatically alter scaleX attribute on VectorDrawable at runtime

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to work with Android Lollipop's new VectorDrawable APIs to have images scale dynamically at runtime(getting smaller and larger depending on application state). As I understand, the scaleX and scaleY attributes of the group element of such a drawable are what cause it to be enlarged or shrunk. Upon looking through the APIs, I've attempted the following to no avail:

```
    Resources.Theme theme=getResources().newTheme();
    theme.applyStyle(R.style.HowAboutThisScale, true);

    ImageView vectorView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_view);
    VectorDrawable vectorTest=(VectorDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);

    vectorTest.mutate();

    vectorTest.applyTheme(theme);
    vectorView.setImageDrawable(vectorTest);
```

with this as the theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="HowAboutThisScale">
    <item name="android:scaleX">10</item>
    <item name="android:scaleY">10</item>
</style>
```

however, that does not work at all. I am sure that I'm doing something wrong with this, mostly due to the fact I don't have much experience with modifying other Drawables at runtime. Does anybody know any way to implement something like this?

Comment: That's not how themes and styles work, and most developers should never call either `Theme.applyStyle()` or `Drawable.applyTheme()`. That aside, there are no APIs available on `VectorDrawable` to access individual groups. You are probably better off treating it like any other drawable and using either `ScaleDrawable` and `setLevel()` or scaling the `ImageView` itself within a container.

Comment: Is there a method when scaling the surrounding ImageView itself to maintain the image's integrity when enlarging it?

Comment: `VectorDrawable` only updates its cached bitmap when the drawable bounds change, so you could animate the size of the `ImageView`. You could also consider using an [`AnimatedVectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html).

Comment: By wrapping the VectorDrawables in ScaleDrawables and adjusting their levels, I was able to get the results I needed. Thank you.